# Remover teclado em aplicativo ReactNative (Coletor de dados)

Tags: react-native

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em react-native para um coletor de dados(android), porém como a tela é pequena e ele já tem um teclado físico, o cliente está me pedindo para remover o teclado virtual quando clica em um input e não estou conseguindo.
Tentei usar o `keyboard.dismiss()`, porém ele tira o focus do campo. É possível essa remoção?

Comment: já tentou? `<TextInput showSoftInputOnFocus={false} />`

Comment: Deu certo. obrigado